# How do I affect row margin if I change col padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't figure out this one, would love some insight. If I change bootstraps default column padding, how should i change the row negative margin? Is it equal to the amount of the padding the col's have? This is what I have in my LESS file.

```
/* ROWS & COLUMNS */
@col-gutter: 20px;

/***********************************************************/
/***********************************************************/
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12{
 padding-left: @col-gutter;
 padding-right: @col-gutter;
}
.row{
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

If I change the columns to 20px padding, how should I change the row?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the `padding` in your **row** must be exactly the same that you're appling in you col's, but negative, as you already know.  ;)

The class **row** is used to remove space between the begin of your container and the first col element, and between the last col element and the end of your container.

So... yep! It need to have the same `padding`.

I hope this can help you. :)